# From headers mail php

Tags: php, email, email-headers

When I try to add headers in mail function it doesn't work.
However, my code seems to be good.

Maybe we can't make a dynamic 'From' header ?

```
var message = "";
var nomClient = $("#nom").val();
var mailClient = $("#mail").val();

$.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: "traitement.php",
          data: { monMessage: message, mailDuClient: mailClient, nomDuClient: nomClient }
      })

      /* Si succès */
      .done(function() {
           // Bug : le champs mail restait visible, donc on le cache
           $("#mail").addClass("cacher");
           // Affiche le message de succès
           $(".succes").animate().css("display", "block");
           // On attends 3,5 secondes puis on rafraichi la page
           setTimeout(function(){location.reload();}, 3500);
       })

       /* Si échec */
       .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           alert('Un problème est survenu');
       });
```

And this is my PHP code :

```
$to = "x.y@gmail.com";
$objet = "Nouvelle demande de devis";
$headers = 'From: '. $_POST['nomDuClient'] . ' <' .$_POST['mailDuClient']. '>'. "\r\n";
 //'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(). "\r\n";

$mail = mail($to, $objet, $_POST['monMessage'], $headers);
echo($mail);
```

The mail is correctly sent, but without "From"

Comment: Instead of `PHP` mail function try using `PHPMailer` class

Comment: I think I don't have time do add a new class .. Actually the mail is correctly sent if the mail address is ok ! For example jean.dupont@gmail.com is working BUT a@gmail.com is not working ...

Comment: If you put user-supplied data (`$_POST`) directly into your mail headers without sanitising them you are effectively creating a mail relay. Spammers **will** find and exploit it. (for example: by setting `$_POST['mailDuClient']` to `some-email@example.com>\r\nTo: long-list-of-emails@example.com\r\nSubject: Spam\r\n\r\n`) Instead you should use a library like PHPMailer that has solved this kind of problem already.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with the code you provided. What you can do is this:

```
$to = "x.y@gmail.com";
$objet = "Nouvelle demande de devis";
$headers = 'From: '. $_POST['nomDuClient'] . ' <' .$_POST['mailDuClient']. '>'. "\r\n";
 //'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(). "\r\n";

$message = "headers:[$headers]\nmessage:\n".$_POST['monMessage']

$mail = mail($to, $objet, $message, $headers);
echo($mail);
```

This way you will receive a mail with the headers in the message itself. There you can see whether they are correct, or if something is missing.

Comment: I don't want to put the headers in the mail ^^ But if the mail address is wrong (for exemple it doesn't exist), the mail would be sent as well ?

Comment: I know you don't want to put the headers in the mail. But you have a problem with your headers, so you need to debug your code. One way of debugging is to look at what is in the headers. A simple way of doing that is to put them in your email. About your unrelated question: Yes, PHP will try to send all emails, your mailserver will fail to do so if the `to:` mail address doesn't exist.

Comment: I modified my code like this : $headers = 'From:' . $_POST['mailDuClient'] . "\r\n"; and now the mail is sent BUT NOT WITH a@gmail.com address ... If i put others address it's working ! @KIKO Software your code is working, in my mail I have the good values for 'From' and 'To'

Comment: Ah, I understand. By "it doesn't work" you actually mean: "I don't receive the email"? So your PHP code works, but your mailserver refuses to send the mail when the `From:` address is invalid? In that case this is a mail server issue, not a PHP issue.

Comment: Yes exactly, I think it's not php .. It's working when it's like a@hotmail.fr but not with gmail .. Thanks